# Installing Phusion Passenger as a dynamic Nginx module; module doesn't seem to load but no errors

Tags: nginx, module, passenger

I'm trying to install Phusion Passenger as a dynamic module with Nginx installed from the repo. The process seems to be working but my Meteor app doesn't load and it looks like the Passenger module isn't running.

OS: RedHat 8

Nginx: 1.20.1

Passenger: Standalone 6.0.12

Meteor: 2.5.1

How I've built the module:

1. Install Passenger standalone as per the [tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/installations/oss/ownserver/meteor/standalone/)
2. [Install passenger-devel](https://linux-packages.com/centos-8/package/passenger-develx86-64)

```
sudo dnf install passenger-devel.x86_64
```

3. Check installation

```
sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
```

This shows "Everything looks good"

4. Check the Passenger module path

```
passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir
```

returns

```
/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module
```

and

```
sudo ls /usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module
```

shows

```
config       ContentHandler.c  ngx_http_passenger_module.c  StaticContentHandler.h
ConfigGeneral    ContentHandler.h  ngx_http_passenger_module.h
Configuration.c  LocationConfig    README.md
Configuration.h  MainConfig    StaticContentHandler.c
```

5. Install PCRE

```
sudo yum install pcre-devel
```

6. Install Nginx from repo

```
sudo yum module list nginx
sudo yum module reset nginx
sudo yum module enable nginx:1.20
sudo yum install nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

7. Download Nginx source code

```
wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.20.1.tar.gz
tar zxf nginx-1.20.1.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.20.1/
```

8. Check compile flags:

```
nginx -V
```

9. Used the output of `nginx -V` to construct and then run the `configure` command (though as the output showed --wtih-compat I could probably have used `./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=$(passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir)` instead)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/./configure --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-debug --with-file-aio --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-threads --add-dynamic-module=$(passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir)
```

10. Build the Passenger module and copy it to where Nginx can find it

```
make modules
sudo cp objs/ngx_http_passenger_module.so /usr/share/nginx/modules/
```

11. Tell Nginx to load the module

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
load_module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so";
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
```

I also commented out the default server block.

12. Configure my app (which is already unpacked in /var/www/myapp and I know from previous tests that it works with Nginx and Passenger installed from the repo)

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf
```

Extract from the conf file:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name myserveraddress;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/myapp/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;

    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    passenger_app_root /var/www/myapp/bundle;
...
```

13. Restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

I now visit the web page but see a 404 not found page. In the logs I see only this:

```
"/var/www/myapp/bundle/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

There are no other errors, warnings or info.

This suggests to me that Nginx is loading my config file or it wouldn't be looking in /var/www/myapp/bundle. But it doesn't seem to have enabled Passenger, as it's still looking for public/index.html instead of main.js.

I can't find any way to inspect Nginx to see what dynamic modules are running, and I've tried setting the log level to debug. I'd be grateful for any suggestions how to find out what's going on / how to enable the Passenger module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out; the issue was that I didn't realise that when you install Passenger as a dynamic module, you still need to do the same config as with a regular install. In particular, in your nginx.conf, you need to add this to the http block:

```
  passenger_root /usr/share/passenger-6.0.12;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

passenger_root should be where your passenger is installed, which you can find by running:

```
passenger-config --root
```

And passenger_ruby is your ruby file.

I hadn't previously understood that in all configurations, Passenger must be installed and the module file `ngx_http_passenger_module.so` is just the glue to tell nginx how to talk to it. Without passenger_root, nginx will act as though the passenger module is not installed.